# Mat-Select dropdown doesn't select any of options

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-material

so I load my form with patch value, and for some reason, the mat-select doesn't select based on the value.

Here is what I have:

```
    constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private productServices : ProductsService,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private router : Router) { 
          this.moods=[
              {mood: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
              {mood: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
              {mood: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
            
          ];
          }
        

      ngOnInit() {
        
            this.completeProfileForm = this._formBuilder.group({
              title :['',Validators.required],
              releaseDate: ['', Validators.required],
              resolution: ['', Validators.required],
              displayName: ['', Validators.required],
              description: ['', Validators.required],
              type: ['', Validators.required],
              primary_mood: ['', Validators.required],
              secondary_mood: ['', Validators.required],
              price: [null, Validators.required],
              
            });
      }
    <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="fill">
                    <mat-label>Primary Mood</mat-label>
                    <mat-select formControlName="primary_mood" >
                      <mat-option *ngFor="let mood of moods" [value]="mood.value">
                        {{mood.mood}}
                      </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="completeProfileForm.controls.primary_mood.touched && completeProfileForm.controls.primary_mood.invalid">
                        <span *ngIf="completeProfileForm.controls.primary_mood.errors.required">Please select your artwork Type.</span>
                    </mat-error>
                  </mat-form-field>
```

[i tried to select any of the options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/434Pe.png)
[the options not selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ6AY.png)

can u guys help me please

Comment: The data type is `{mood: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'}` but you used `[value]="mood.value"` not `mood.viewValue` in HTML. Is it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Julian Liu. You have a typo in your HTML. You say

```
[value]="mood.value"
```

but in your object the field is named `viewValue`.

Correct your HTML this way:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let mood of moods" [value]="mood.viewValue">
                    {{mood.mood}}
                  </mat-option>
```

To see your result keep my further suggestion and put this piece of code at the end of `ngOnInit()`.

```
this.completeProfileForm.get('primary_mood').valueChanges.subscribe(selection => console.log('you selected: ' + selection));
```

You should now see your selection in the console. Now you have to find a way to make use of it.

Comment: the result is :you selected: undefined

Comment: Sorry pal, I did not see your typo. I adjusted my answer according to it.